# Is DXUT deprecated?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm starting on a new project and was thinking of using DXUT.  On the Microsoft site though, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page says the content has moved to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.  And on that second page, which is an overview of DirectX components, there's no mention of DXUT.

Is DXUT deprecated now?

Comment: As far as I know the use of DXUT in a project was never really encouraged by MS in the first place.

Comment: @melak47 That's too bad. Does that mean I have to write a slider from scratch?

Comment: An updated DXUT can be obtained [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437).

Comment: @Pierre For simple developer UI I've been using [AntTweakBar](http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/) lately as a DXUT replacement and I'm quite happy with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DXUT was primarily used to drive DirectX samples, and really that's about all it was good for -- it was itself always shipped in the samples directory of the SDK.

Modern (that is, for Windows 8) samples seem to directly include "DirectXApp" classes that drive the basic equivalent functionality that DXUT provided. I don't believe DXUT itself has survived the transition because I don't see it in the samples directory linked off of the [second page you provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But that's fine, since it wasn't really worth using for production applications.

EDIT: However, as of September 2013, as Chuck notes above, a standalone updated to DXUT [can be obtained](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437).

Comment: So DXUT was rather like GLUT then.

Comment: I believe that the similarities in the naming may not have been entirely uncoincidental.

Answer (score 9):

To the original question: DXUT has historically been the sample framework for the DirectX SDK. Officially the DirectX SDK is now deprecated, and along with it the D3DX utility library that DXUT used to use. Also, DXUT only works for Win32 desktop applications, and is not supported for Windows Store apps, Windows phone 8, Xbox One, etc.

The GitHub version of DXUT is basically a cleaned up DXUT11 from the legacy DirectX SDK (June 2010). It no longer has any dependencies on the legacy DirectX SDK and can be built using just VS 2012 or VS 2013 with the Windows 8.x SDK. it includes some helper code (DDSTextureLoader, WICTextureLoader, ScreenGrab) from the DirectXTex/DirectX Tool Kit projects but otherwise is 'standalone'. I used this version of DXUT to scrub out the legacy DirectX SDK dependencies of a number of [old samples](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/).

DXUT was never really recommended for use for 'production' applications as it was primarily about making it easier to write samples, but some people found it useful as a the basis of their work.

See this [blog](https://walbourn.github.io/dxut-for-win32-desktop-update/) post.

**NOTE** For simple projects and developer education, another option instead of using DXUT is to use [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) which supports all the modern Microsoft platforms in combination with the [Direct3D Game template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).

Comment: What's is the actual reason that DXUT is not recommended for DXUT e.g. what could be improved in DXUT?

Comment: This is a complex discussion out of the scope of a quick StackOverflow comment, but in summary: (A) DXUT is not being brought forward to Direct3D 12, (B) DXUT only works for Windows desktop apps and does not support Windows 10 UWP, Windows 8.x Store, Windows phone 8.x, or Xbox One, (C) DXUT is entirely mouse/keyboard based and has no touch support (save legacy behaviors), (D) the last 'official' release was the state it was in the DirectX SDK (June 2010) and the open source version is essentially my personal passion project and has only minimal test coverage.

Comment: All that said, if it works for your project then that's fine. It's *never* been recommended as the basis for a commercial engine or game although a few teams have in the past done just that. It's primary use has always been as a vehicle for developer education and samples. In fact, my main motivation for doing the [open source](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437) version was to be able to publish the [catalog of DirectX SDK samples](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples) online in a way that did not require using the legacy DirectX SDK.